# Настройка сети на lxc

Tags: debian, виртуализация, lxc

Установил lxc, создал контейнер. Все делал по этой инструкции [ссылка](http://xgu.ru/wiki/LXC)

Купил дополнительный ip для этого контейнера и согласно инструкции прописал настройки. Только беда в том, что я не могу после этого подключится к нему по ssh, выдает ошибку

```
ssh: connect to host 213.239.197.122 port 22: No route to host
```

Что вводил:
в файл ***/etc/network/interfaces***

```
auto br0 
iface br0 inet static
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_fd 0 
address 213.239.197.111
broadcast 213.239.197.127
netmask 255.255.255.224
gateway 213.239.197.97


iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2a01:4f8:130:622e::2
netmask 64
```

В файл ***/var/lib/lxc/test_01/config***

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags        = up
lxc.network.name         = eth1
lxc.network.link         = br0
lxc.network.veth.pair    = veth-01
lxc.network.ipv4         = 213.239.197.122
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 213.239.197.97
lxc.network.hwaddr       = 00:50:56:00:9C:81
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/office/rootfs

# Common configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/debian.common.conf

# Container specific configuration
lxc.mount = /var/lib/lxc/office/fstab
lxc.utsname = office
lxc.arch = amd64
lxc.autodev = 1
lxc.kmsg = 0
```

Система - Debian 8

Answer (score 1):

Надо было в файл ***/etc/network/interfaces*** прописать строку

```
post-up /sbin/ip ro add 213.239.197.122/32 dev br0
```